# OpenGL: Draw an arrow

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I'd like to know how to draw an arrow to represent a vector position, length and direction.

The issue is that I can't quite find an easy way to know the location and rotation of the triangle representing the arrow head.

If it can help, I'm using OpenGL/OpenTK(wrapper for C#).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do:

Have your standard arrow draw from (0, 0, 0) to (1, 0, 0) (using a line) and the tip of the arrow be a triangle at the end (using a triangle, points at (0.95, 0, +/-0.025) and (1, 0, 0)). Then resize your arrow to the size you need with a scale matrix (since it's a unit vector, it's easy to have it the desired size) and then move your arrow to wherever you need it with a translation and a rotation matrix.

And you can reuse it wherever you like!

Of course, you have to decide where you want it first, and remember that it is pointing in x+ when moving it around..!